# jasmine matchers TypeError: expect(...).toHaveClass is not a function (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, karma-jasmine

I am new to this jasmine and karma. I am trying to execute the following test case. I want to test if HTML element has specific class exist or not? I have added the reference of jasmine-jquery and other required js file.

```
describe("testing html dom element", function(){
it("It should match the value", function() {
    var fixture = setFixtures('<div class="post">foo</div>')
    var post = fixture.find('.post');
    expect($('<div class="some-class"></div>')).toHaveClass("some-class")
});
});
```

This is my karma config file.

```
    files: [
   // 'node_modules/jasmine',
    'node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css',
    'node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js',
    'node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js',
    'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js',
    'node_modules/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js',
    '*.html',
    'app/*.js',
    'test/*.js'
],
```

This what error I am getting.
[image]

Any help please?
I do apologize if this is basic error as I am new to this Jasmine and Karma things.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add `'jasmine-jquery'` to the frameworks on `karma.conf.js`

```
frameworks: ['jasmine-jquery','jasmine'],
```

https://github.com/bessdsv/karma-jasmine-jquery#usage